# How to clear android app log message programmatically?

Tags: android, android-logcat

In my android app, I read my Log messages. After reading the log message I want to clear it. So I tried following code for clearing the app's log .

```
ProcessBuilder().command("logcat", "-c").redirectErrorStream(true).start()
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("logcat", "-c"))
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c")
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -b all -c")
```

But above code is not cleared the log message. But whenever I used `adb logcat -c` from PC's command prompt it works properly. So how to clear the logs pro grammatically in android.

Comment: why you need to do this

Answer (score 0):

There is no way u can write a code to clear the logcat in Android Studio but there is a way u can clear logcat every time u run an app.
Follow these steps:
1. RUN
2.Edit Configuration
3. Then when the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog shows up, click the Logcat tab (now called Miscellaneous in Android Studio 2.x)(idk about if u are in the latest version)
4. U will see a "Clear log before launch" checkbox, now click on it check it.
5. Ur logcat output will be cleared before each new run in Android Studio.
Hope this helped u.

Comment: I want to clear the log in the app not in android studio.

Comment: ook misunderstanding but i think u cant do that. Google it if i m wrong